# Deleting nested display list in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a question regarding the deletion of a nested display list in OpenGL. A display list can simply be created by:

```
    GLuint myList = glGenLists(1);
    glNewList(myList, GL_COMPILE);
    // ...code for objects in list...
    glEndList();
```

If I'm not mistaken, such a list is simply deleted by:

```
    glDeleteLists(myList, 1);
```

Now a display list can also be nested, such that each a list contains another, or multiple display lists. The code would be of the form:

```
    GLuint parentList = glGenLists(1);      // ID = 1
    glNewList(parentList , GL_COMPILE);

    GLuint childList1 = glGenLists(1);      // ID = 2
    glNewList(childList1 , GL_COMPILE); 
    // .. code for some objects here
    glEndList();

    GLuint childList2 = glGenLists(1);      // ID = 3
    glNewList(childList2, GL_COMPILE); 
    // .. code for more objects here
    glEndList();

    glEndList();
```

But my question is, how do I delete such a nested list? Is it enough to glDeleteList(.) only the parent, or should also its children be deleted individually? And in the latter case: does the order matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

glNewList is *not* recorded when in the middle of a COMPILE. [It generates an error instead.](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glNewList.xml)

```
GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if [...] glNewList is called 
while a display list is being defined
```

So these "nested" lists do not exist.

Comment: Thanks! Interesting though, because there are too many websites that refer to a nested display list as something real, although none of them seems to give any example. Even on the OpenGL website, it is mentioned in the FAQ:
"16.030 How does display list nesting work? Is the called list copied into the calling list?"
http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/displaylist.htm

But the answer is very non-descriptive too...

Comment: Well, nested display list is about _calling_ display lists inside a display list. glNewList is not recorded, but glCallLists is.